# ajax datatable, cannot retrieve data

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I Edited my code, but the problem now is i can't retrieve my data but there is no error in my code, Also i have records in my database. I can't figure it out why my data is not dislaying.
//Controller - where i getting my data in database.

```
 public ActionResult GetEmployeeFlexiSched()
        {
    string query = "exec spdGetEmployeeFlexiSched";
    string strReturn = GlobalFunction.DataTableToJSON(GlobalFunction.TableFromMSSQL(conn, query));
            return Json(new { success = true, data = strReturn }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
    var dataTable = $('#OedTB').DataTable({
        "language": {
        emptyTable: "No Transaction"
            },
        ajax: {
         url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeFlexiSched", "FlexiSchedule")',
         dataType: "json",
         retrieve: "true",
         processing: "true",
         serverSide: "true",
         type: "POST",
         dataSrc: "",
            },
         order: [],
         columnDefs: [
         {
          orderable: false,
         }
           ],
        columns: [
        {data: "TranNo"},
        {data: "FullName"},
                {
                data: "TranNo",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<button type="button" class="btn btm-sm btn-outline-danger viewdetails" id="' + data + '"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button>';
                   }
                   },
                    ]

                });
    });

     </script>
```

Comment: when you are using ajax , then define in datatable like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) you dont need to create rows yourself. and  also share your json

Comment: Can `console.log` the `result` variable, and paste the code snippet into your question?

Comment: You have `dataType: "json"` so jQuery will already parse the response as JSON. You don't need to parse it again